# Development node.js server on localhost returns nil in swiftUI app but not in browser

Tags: ios, node.js, express, server, swiftui

I am having this problem with a swiftUI app connecting to my local node.js rest api.

I have the node.js file running on localhost, I even got it to run on https but everytime I call the get url I am getting a return value of nil. Also I am just testing this on the local simulator.

Here is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan')
const mysql = require('mysql')

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app).listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening...')
})

app.use(morgan('combined'))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("responding to root route")
  res.send("Hello from roooooot")
})

app.get('/users/:username',(req,res) => {
  console.log("Fetching user: " + req.params.username)
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'kneckt'
  })

  const username = req.params.username
  const queryString = "SELECT * FROM kneckt.user WHERE username = ?"

  connection.query(queryString,[username],(err, rows, fields) =>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      res.sendStatus(500)
      return
    }

    console.log("I think we fetched users successfully")

    const users = rows.map((row) => {
      return{username: row.username,email: row.email}
    })
    res.json(users)
  })
  //res.end()
})

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'kneckt'
  })

  const queryString = "SELECT * FROM kneckt.user"

  connection.query(queryString,(err, rows, fields) =>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
      res.sendStatus(500)
      return
    }

    console.log("I think we fetched users successfully")

    const users = rows.map((row) => {
      return{username: row.username,email: row.email,id: row.userID, firstName: row.first_name,lastName:row.last_name,school: row.school,image:row.image,status: row.status}
    })
    res.json(users)
  })

})
```

and here is my swift file with the git command:

```
class API {
    
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<API, Never>()
    
    var friends = [Friend]() {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    func getFriends(completion: @escaping ([Friend]) -> ()){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://localhost:3000/users") else { return }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Hello for some reason nothing is being delivered")
                return}
            let friends = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Friend].self, from: data)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.friends = friends
            }
        }
    .resume()
    }
}
```

I always receive my error message "hello for some reason nothing is being delivered."

Any insight would be great.

Also I can access the api on the browser on the ios simulator and it returns the correct json. So I feel like it is something to do with the app itself.

Comment: Would you show your SwiftUI code?

Comment: Bro how did you connect swift with node.js? I can't find any guide and I'm trying to make a todo app. Would you be so kind to tell me where did you find the guide?

Comment: @Arturo Hey sorry for the late response! There are a couple options. One you can host the node.js on Heroku for free! I did this following this playlist [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=F7NVpxxmmgM&list=PUuP2vJ6kRutQBfRmdcI92mA&index=45&ab_channel=LetsBuildThatApp)

Comment: @Arturo if you want to run it on your local machine you have to find a way to make node.js run on https not http. I did this using ngrok. Using ngrok.com follow steps to run the program for self certification for localhost server and point it to your server url a. Follow this link for help: [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4LDsxSzZeI) b. You will need to take the new url given and replace the one in the API class inside swift

Comment: @Arturo Hope this helps!

Comment: @gtgaito thanks. Do you know of a good way to use realtime data in macOS? To be able to create a cross-platform app

Comment: @Arturo Can you elaborate? Not sure what you mean. You can create a backend and fill it with real data and run it locally on your machine.